# Android application connecting to wifi printer to take print

Tags: android

I am new to android programming,I got a chance to work with (wifi printers).In my application I have a pdf file which needs to be taken a printout by using wifi printer

I didnt have much idea on this,but after doing a research  I got that,there are 3 things to be done for doing this

1)getting the list of devices which are connected to wifi network which my mobile is using right now.

2) Then,select a device and make a connection with that device.

3) Transfer data to a printer

```
    I hope these are the steps which I need to use.
```

I worked on first point,but I am getting the (Wifi networks like Tata communications,vonline etc) but not the devices which are connecting to that networks.

Here is the code I used.........

```
public class WiFiDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener
 {      
    WifiManager wifi;       
    ListView lv;
    TextView textStatus;
    Button buttonScan;
    int size = 0;
    List<ScanResult> results;

    String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter;

    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }   
        this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(WiFiDemo.this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
        lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
            {
               results = wifi.getScanResults();
               size = results.size();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));                    
    }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        arraylist.clear();          
        wifi.startScan();
        checkWifi();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try 
        {
            size = size - 1;
            while (size >= 0) 
            {   
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();                       
                item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID + "  " + results.get(size).capabilities);

                arraylist.add(item);
                size--;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }         
    } 
    private void checkWifi(){      
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        final WifiManager wifiManager = 
                            (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);;
                             registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               Log.d("wifi","Open Wifimanager");

               String scanList = wifiManager.getScanResults().toString();
               Log.d("wifi","Scan:"+scanList);
           }           
         },filter);        
           wifiManager.startScan();
         }
}
```

please suggest for the solution

Thanks in advance friends

Comment: can you please send me the code ,i also have a same requirement to print the page using wifiprinter,please post your answer

Comment: hello....have you solved your problem or not?

Comment: @user1891910 : Have you got the solution? I also have same requirement. Please post your answer.

Comment: hi did you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [Android-wifi-print - Github](https://github.com/SureshCS-50/Android-wifi-print), Which contains a demo application I created for the same.

**Edit :**

As @NileshThakkar said. we may lost connection to that link in future so, I am posting code here.. with flow.

1. checks connectivity.
2. If connected in WiFi.. am storing that WiFi configuration.
3. Now checking whether I already have printer's information (WiFi configuration of WiFi printer) is available or not. If available, I'll scan and get list of WiFi ScanResults and connects to that else.. It'll showing list of WiFi and clicking on that, user will connect to printer and stores that WiFi configuration for future printing jobs.
4. After print job completes, I'm connecting to my previous WiFi or Mobile data connection.
5. Now going back to 2nd step.
6. If user connected in Mobile data, I'm just enabling WiFi and following 3rd step.
7. After Print job completes, I'm just disabling WiFi. so that, We'll be connected back to Mobile data connection. (That is android default).

Libraries : gson-2.2.4, itextpdf-5.4.3

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements PrintCompleteService {

    private Button mBtnPrint;

    private WifiConfiguration mPrinterConfiguration, mOldWifiConfiguration;
    private WifiManager mWifiManager;
    private List<ScanResult> mScanResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
    private WifiScanner mWifiScanner;

    private PrintManager mPrintManager;
    private List<PrintJob> mPrintJobs;
    private PrintJob mCurrentPrintJob;

    private File pdfFile;
    private String externalStorageDirectory;

    private Handler mPrintStartHandler = new Handler();
    private Handler mPrintCompleteHandler = new Handler();
    private String connectionInfo;

    private boolean isMobileDataConnection = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = new File(externalStorageDirectory, Constants.CONTROLLER_RX_PDF_FOLDER);
            pdfFile = new File(folder, "Print_testing.pdf");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        mWifiScanner = new WifiScanner();

        mBtnPrint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrint);

        mBtnPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                connectionInfo = Util.connectionInfo(MyActivity.this);

                if (connectionInfo.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.CONTROLLER_MOBILE)) {
                    isMobileDataConnection = true;

                    if (mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enabling WiFi..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    }

                    mWifiManager.startScan();

                    printerConfiguration();

                } else if (connectionInfo.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.CONTROLLER_WIFI)) {
                    Util.storeCurrentWiFiConfiguration(MyActivity.this);

                    printerConfiguration();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Please connect to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            registerReceiver(mWifiScanner, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
            mWifiManager.startScan();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mWifiScanner);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void printerConfiguration() {

        mPrinterConfiguration = Util.getWifiConfiguration(MyActivity.this, Constants.CONTROLLER_PRINTER);

        if (mPrinterConfiguration == null) {
            showWifiListActivity(Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PRINTER);

        } else {

            boolean isPrinterAvailable = false;

            mWifiManager.startScan();

            for (int i = 0; i < mScanResults.size(); i++) {
                if (mPrinterConfiguration.SSID.equals("\"" + mScanResults.get(i).SSID + "\"")) {
                    isPrinterAvailable = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrinterAvailable) {

                connectToWifi(mPrinterConfiguration);

                doPrint();

            } else {
                showWifiListActivity(Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PRINTER);
            }

        }
    }

    private void connectToWifi(WifiConfiguration mWifiConfiguration) {
        mWifiManager.enableNetwork(mWifiConfiguration.networkId, true);
    }

    private void showWifiListActivity(int requestCode) {
        Intent iWifi = new Intent(this, WifiListActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(iWifi, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(int status) {

        mPrintJobs = mPrintManager.getPrintJobs();

        mPrintCompleteHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mPrintCompleteHandler.postDelayed(this, 2000);

                if (mCurrentPrintJob.getInfo().getState() == PrintJobInfo.STATE_COMPLETED) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < mPrintJobs.size(); i++) {
                        if (mPrintJobs.get(i).getId() == mCurrentPrintJob.getId()) {
                            mPrintJobs.remove(i);
                        }
                    }

                    switchConnection();

                    mPrintCompleteHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                } else if (mCurrentPrintJob.getInfo().getState() == PrintJobInfo.STATE_FAILED) {
                    switchConnection();
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Print Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPrintCompleteHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                } else if (mCurrentPrintJob.getInfo().getState() == PrintJobInfo.STATE_CANCELED) {
                    switchConnection();
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Print Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPrintCompleteHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                }

            }
        }, 2000);

    }

    public void switchConnection() {
        if (!isMobileDataConnection) {
            mOldWifiConfiguration = Util.getWifiConfiguration(MyActivity.this, Constants.CONTROLLER_WIFI);

            boolean isWifiAvailable = false;

            mWifiManager.startScan();

            for (int i = 0; i < mScanResults.size(); i++) {
                if (mOldWifiConfiguration.SSID.equals("\"" + mScanResults.get(i).SSID + "\"")) {
                    isWifiAvailable = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isWifiAvailable) {
                connectToWifi(mOldWifiConfiguration);
            } else {
                showWifiListActivity(Constants.REQUEST_CODE_WIFI);
            }
        } else {
            mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void printDocument(File pdfFile) {
        mPrintManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";

        mCurrentPrintJob = mPrintManager.print(jobName, new PrintServicesAdapter(MyActivity.this, pdfFile), null);
    }

    public void doPrint() {
        mPrintStartHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.d("PrinterConnection Status", "" + mPrinterConfiguration.status);

                mPrintStartHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);

                if (mPrinterConfiguration.status == WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT) {
                    if (Util.computePDFPageCount(pdfFile) > 0) {
                        printDocument(pdfFile);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Can't print, Page count is zero.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    mPrintStartHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                } else if (mPrinterConfiguration.status == WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Failed to connect to printer!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPrintStartHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                }
            }
        }, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PRINTER && resultCode == Constants.RESULT_CODE_PRINTER) {
            mPrinterConfiguration = Util.getWifiConfiguration(MyActivity.this, Constants.CONTROLLER_PRINTER);
            doPrint();
        }
    }

    public class WifiScanner extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
            Log.e("scan result size", "" + mScanResults.size());
        }
    }

}
```

**WiFiListActivity.java**

```
public class WifiListActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ListView mListWifi;
    private Button mBtnScan;

    private WifiManager mWifiManager;
    private WifiAdapter adapter;
    private WifiListener mWifiListener;

    private List<ScanResult> mScanResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_list);

        mBtnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        mBtnScan.setOnClickListener(this);

        mListWifi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wifiList);

        mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled.. making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        mWifiListener = new WifiListener();

        adapter = new WifiAdapter(WifiListActivity.this, mScanResults);
        mListWifi.setAdapter(adapter);

        mListWifi.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                connectToWifi(i);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mWifiManager.startScan();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            registerReceiver(mWifiListener, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
            mWifiManager.startScan();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mWifiListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void connectToWifi(int position) {

        final ScanResult item = mScanResults.get(position);

        String Capabilities = item.capabilities;

        if (Capabilities.contains("WPA")) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WifiListActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Password:");

            final EditText input = new EditText(WifiListActivity.this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
                    wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + item.SSID + "\"";
                    wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + m_Text + "\"";
                    wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = true;
                    wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA); // For WPA
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN); // For WPA2
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
                    int res = mWifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
                    boolean b = mWifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);

                    finishActivity(wifiConfiguration, res);

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();


        } else if (Capabilities.contains("WEP")) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WifiListActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Title");

            final EditText input = new EditText(WifiListActivity.this);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
                    wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + item.SSID + "\"";
                    wifiConfiguration.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + m_Text + "\"";
                    wifiConfiguration.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                    int res = mWifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
                    Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res);
                    boolean b = mWifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
                    Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b);

                    finishActivity(wifiConfiguration, res);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();

        } else {

            WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
            wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"" + item.SSID + "\"";
            wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            int res = mWifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
            Log.d("WifiPreference", "add Network returned " + res);
            boolean b = mWifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
            Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b);

            finishActivity(wifiConfiguration, res);
        }

    }

    private void finishActivity(WifiConfiguration mWifiConfiguration, int networkId) {

        mWifiConfiguration.networkId = networkId;

        Util.savePrinterConfiguration(WifiListActivity.this, mWifiConfiguration);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(Constants.RESULT_CODE_PRINTER, intent);
        finish();
    }

    public class WifiListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
            Log.e("scan result size ", "" + mScanResults.size());
            adapter.setElements(mScanResults);
        }
    }
}
```

**WifiAdapter.java**

```
public class WifiAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private List<ScanResult> mWifiList = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();

    public WifiAdapter(Activity mActivity, List<ScanResult> mWifiList) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mWifiList = mWifiList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mWifiList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mWifiList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_wifi_list_item, null);

        TextView txtWifiName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtWifiName);
        txtWifiName.setText(mWifiList.get(i).SSID);

        return view;
    }

    public void setElements(List<ScanResult> mWifis) {
        this.mWifiList = mWifis;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**PrintCompleteService.java**

```
public interface PrintCompleteService {
    public void onMessage(int status);
}
```

**PrintServiceAdapter.java**

```
public class PrintServicesAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private int pageHeight;
    private int pageWidth;
    private PdfDocument myPdfDocument;
    private int totalpages = 1;
    private File pdfFile;
    private PrintCompleteService mPrintCompleteService;

    public PrintServicesAdapter(Activity mActivity, File pdfFile) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.pdfFile = pdfFile;
        this.totalpages = Util.computePDFPageCount(pdfFile);
        this.mPrintCompleteService = (PrintCompleteService) mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes,
                         PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                         CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                         LayoutResultCallback callback,
                         Bundle metadata) {
        myPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(mActivity, newAttributes);

        pageHeight =
                newAttributes.getMediaSize().getHeightMils() / 1000 * 72;
        pageWidth =
                newAttributes.getMediaSize().getWidthMils() / 1000 * 72;

        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            return;
        }

        if (totalpages > 0) {
            PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo
                    .Builder(pdfFile.getName())
                    .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                    .setPageCount(totalpages);

            PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
            callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
        } else {
            callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count is zero.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWrite(final PageRange[] pageRanges,
                        final ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                        final CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                        final WriteResultCallback callback) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;


        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
            output = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});


        } catch (FileNotFoundException ee) {
            //Catch exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Catch exception
        } finally {
            try {
                input.close();
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        cancellationSignal.setOnCancelListener(new CancellationSignal.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                mPrintCompleteService.onMessage(Constants.PRINTER_STATUS_CANCELLED);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        mPrintCompleteService.onMessage(Constants.PRINTER_STATUS_COMPLETED);
    }
}
```

**Util.java**

```
public class Util {

    public static String connectionInfo(Activity mActivity) {
        String result = "not connected";

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.CONTROLLER_WIFI)) {
                if (ni.isConnected()) {
                    result = Constants.CONTROLLER_WIFI;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.CONTROLLER_MOBILE)) {
                if (ni.isConnected()) {
                    result = Constants.CONTROLLER_MOBILE;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void saveWifiConfiguration(Activity mActivity, WifiConfiguration mWifiConfiguration) {
        Gson mGson = new Gson();
        Type mType = new TypeToken<WifiConfiguration>() {
        }.getType();
        String sJson = mGson.toJson(mWifiConfiguration, mType);
        SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(Constants.DEMO_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mSharedPrefs.edit().putString(Constants.CONTROLLER_WIFI_CONFIGURATION, sJson).commit();
    }

    public static void savePrinterConfiguration(Activity mActivity, WifiConfiguration mPrinterConfiguration) {
        Gson mGson = new Gson();
        Type mType = new TypeToken<WifiConfiguration>() {
        }.getType();
        String sJson = mGson.toJson(mPrinterConfiguration, mType);
        SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(Constants.DEMO_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mSharedPrefs.edit().putString(Constants.CONTROLLER_PRINTER_CONFIGURATION, sJson).commit();
    }

    public static WifiConfiguration getWifiConfiguration(Activity mActivity, String configurationType) {
        WifiConfiguration mWifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
        Gson mGson = new Gson();
        SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(Constants.DEMO_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Type mWifiConfigurationType = new TypeToken<WifiConfiguration>() {
        }.getType();
        String mWifiJson = "";
        if (configurationType.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.CONTROLLER_WIFI)) {
            mWifiJson = mSharedPrefs.getString(Constants.CONTROLLER_WIFI_CONFIGURATION, "");
        } else if (configurationType.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.CONTROLLER_PRINTER)) {
            mWifiJson = mSharedPrefs.getString(Constants.CONTROLLER_PRINTER_CONFIGURATION, "");
        }
        if (!mWifiJson.isEmpty()) {
            mWifiConfiguration = mGson.fromJson(mWifiJson, mWifiConfigurationType);
        } else {
            mWifiConfiguration = null;
        }
        return mWifiConfiguration;
    }

    public static void storeCurrentWiFiConfiguration(Activity mActivity) {
        try {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            final WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            if (connectionInfo != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(connectionInfo.getSSID())) {
                WifiConfiguration mWifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
                mWifiConfiguration.networkId = connectionInfo.getNetworkId();
                mWifiConfiguration.BSSID = connectionInfo.getBSSID();
                mWifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = connectionInfo.getHiddenSSID();
                mWifiConfiguration.SSID = connectionInfo.getSSID();

                // store it for future use -> after print is complete you need to reconnect wifi to this network.
                saveWifiConfiguration(mActivity, mWifiConfiguration);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int computePDFPageCount(File file) {
        RandomAccessFile raf = null;
        int pages = 0;
        try {
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

            RandomAccessFileOrArray pdfFile = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(
                    new RandomAccessSourceFactory().createSource(raf));
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile, new byte[0]);
            pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pages;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You can refer that github link I provided, That has the complete code..
Note: That is a sample project, not lib..

Comment: `itextpdf` has a security issue so it is replaced by `itext7`. It'd be better to change some source code that doesn't work with `itext7`. check- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607530/import-itext-7-in-android-gradle

Comment: And `itext` takes `AGPL` license... If you don't wanna make your own app open source project. Then, you'd better to consider using it.