# In android , How to connect Printer and android phone through WIFI only

Tags: android, wifip2p

Please share full example. I was getting an example of Google cloud printing with hp printers, but I want My mobile should connect with all printers. Even I looked up with Brothers Print SDK for Android, this will work only for brothers printers. As I want Android phone should connect to each and every printer to print document.

Comment: I want a source code that detect  list of wireless printer in my android application, so that I transfer a file  from phone to printer.

Comment: Its not possible to search for Wifi printer without Plug-in install. U can simply try it urself try printing a doc/pic from device with no plug-in installed on device.

Comment: guys please share some code.

Comment: How print share is using multiple plugins in one android application?

Comment: I really don't know much about how did they do. A wild guess is that they smhow managed to discover multiple printers from different manufactures and that make possible to print doc.

Comment: checkout this answer might help u http://stackoverflow.com/a/30828357/1878151

Comment: thanks kevz!! Already check with this. Inside this it is working with printer plugins. In my higher android versions I have google cloud and hp.

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher, the framework provides services for printing images and documents directly from Android applications.

```
/**
 * To print image / photo
 */
private void printPhoto() {
    // Get a PrintHelper instance
    PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(this);
    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    // get image from mipmap folder
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    // provide job name (which will be displayed in the print queue) and bitmap
    photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap);
}
```

Read [Print through android device](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html)