# Can we draw PieChart in PDF using itext Android?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I want to add Pie chart in my PDF using itext in Android. 
But all the example related to piechart seems to use the following 2D classes:

```
Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(width, height,
                    new DefaultFontMapper());   
Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width,
                    height);
```

that are actually awt classes and **not available** in **android version** of itext-5. 
Any alternate to using 2D classses ?

**Edited**: I am using itextg version for android. Its missing 2D classes mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i have found a solution.
I was using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for making the PieChart.
This library has a method for getting the bitmap from the drawn Piechart.

`pieChart.getChartBitmap();`

So, once you get the bitmap, iText will let you add the bitmap into your pdf.
The final code may looks like this:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 Bitmap bitmap = pieChart.getChartBitmap();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
 Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
 myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
 document.add(myImg);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For Android you need to use `itextg` instead of `itextpdf`.

Examples that use classes that are not available on Android, should not be used. When you find a solution, it would be nice if you submitted your documentation.

Comment: Yes. I am already using itextg, and itextg doesn't have 2D classes, required and mentioned above.

Comment: My apologies, your question was not clear because you did not mention that you already use iTextG. I do not have an answer for you.